# Undefined error occurred while i have ran the typecript code in for cucumber file using protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

My feature file :

```
Scenario: Validate cancel button
    When upon clicking hamnurger icon
    When Navigate to Account Details page
    Then cancel the changes in Account detail page
```

Output in the console: Then cancel the changes in Account detail page

Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

```
Then('cancel the changes in Account detail page', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV5FF.png)

Comment: Is the step definition located at the same file as your other definitions?

Comment: I have only two files, one is feature file and the other is xxx.step.ts

Comment: Can you post the step definition declaration please